# Is it possible to turn off a single USB port on a Pi 3?

Tags: usb

I tried [using this library](https://github.com/codazoda/hub-ctrl.c) but it appears to only be able to turn off either the Ethernet port, or all the USB ports, but not an individual USB port.

Also, [turning off all USB ports](http://turning%20off%20all%20the%20USB%20ports) using `Turn off all USB Ports: sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 0 -P 2 -p 0`disables my keyboard, how can I make the ports turn on after 10 seconds automatically?

I can get the BUS and DEV info from lsusb for `sudo ./hub-ctrl -b 001 -d 005 -P1 -p 0`, but where do I get the HUB and PORT information for `sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 3 -P 1 -p 0` (used in the readme file for hub-ctrl.c)

Comment: Found a way to time a turn on command, so I can use my keyboard again  sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 0 -P 2 -p 0 ; sleep 5; sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 0 -P 2 -p 1;